# How to perform set-like operations in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I need to fill a column with values, that are present in a set and not present in any other columns.

initial `df`

```
    c0  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
0   4   5   6   3   2   1
1   1   5   4   0   2   3
2   5   6   4   0   1   3
3   5   4   6   2   0   1
4   5   6   4   0   1   3
5   0   1   4   5   6   2
```

I need `df['c6']` column that is a set-like difference operation product between a set of `set([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])` and each row of `df`

so that the result `df` is

```
    c0  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5   c6
0   4   5   6   3   2   1    0
1   1   5   4   0   2   3    6
2   5   6   4   0   1   3    2
3   5   4   6   2   0   1    3
4   5   6   4   0   1   3    2
5   0   1   4   5   6   2    3
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly different approach:

```
df['c6'] = sum(range(7)) - df.sum(axis=1)
```

or if you want to be more verbose:

```
df['c6'] = sum([0,1,2,3,4,5,6]) - df.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: but would scale quite well for large dataframes because of vectorisation, I think.

Comment: though this approach is not universal, it works best for my particular problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use [numpy setdiff1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html#numpy.setdiff1d) to find the difference between the two arrays and assign the output to column c6

```
ck = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
M = df.to_numpy()
df['c6'] = [np.setdiff1d(ck,i)[0] for i in M]

    c0  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
0   4   5   6   3   2   1   0
1   1   5   4   0   2   3   6
2   5   6   4   0   1   3   2
3   5   4   6   2   0   1   3
4   5   6   4   0   1   3   2
5   0   1   4   5   6   2   3
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way I could think of is using a list comprehension and set difference:

```
s = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
s
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}

df['c6'] = [tuple(s.difference(vals))[0] for vals in df.values]
df
    c0  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
0   4   5   6   3   2   1   0
1   1   5   4   0   2   3   6
2   5   6   4   0   1   3   2
3   5   4   6   2   0   1   3
4   5   6   4   0   1   3   2
5   0   1   4   5   6   2   3
```